# Redux Toolkit - Slice utility methods

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm building a React app with [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and I'm splitting my store into some slices with redux-toolkit's helper function [**createSlice**](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice).

Here it is a simple use case:

```
const sidebar = createSlice({
    name: "sidebar",
    initialState:
    {
        menus: {},      // Keep track of menus states (guid <-> open/close)
        visible: true
    },
    reducers:
    {
        show(state, action)
        {
            state.visible = action.payload.visible;
        },
        setMenuOpen(state, action)
        {
            const { id, open } = action.payload;
            state.menus[id] = open;
            return state;
        }
    }
});
export default sidebar;
```

Everything works fine until I "add" actions (that change the store) to the slice but consider your team looking for an utility function "getMenuOpen": this method doesn't change the store (it's not an **action** and cannot be addeded to *reducers* object). You can of course read directly the data from the store (state.menus[<your_id>]) but consider a more complex example where manipulating the data requires some library imports, more complex code, etc...I want to modularize/hide each slice as much as possible.

Actually I'm using this workaround:

```
const sidebar = createSlice({ /* Same previous code... */ });

sidebar.methods =
{
    getMenuOpen: (state, id) => state.menus[id]
};

export default sidebar;
```

The above code allows importing the slice from a component, mapStateToProps to the redux store, and invoke the utilty function *getMenuOpen* like this:

```
import sidebar from "./Sidebar.slice";

// Component declaration ...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    sidebar: state.ui.layout.sidebar,
    getMenuOpen(id)
    {
        return sidebar.methods.getMenuOpen(this.sidebar, id);
    }
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    setMenuOpen: (id, open) => dispatch(sidebar.actions.setMenuOpen({id, open}))
});
```

The ugly part is that I need to inject the slice node (this.sidebar) as fist param of getMenuOpen because it's not mapped (**as for actions** with reducers/actions) automatically from redux-toolkit.

So my question is: how can I clean my workaround in order to automatically map the store for utility functions? [createSlice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) doesn't seem to support that but maybe some internal redux's api could help me in mapping my "slice.methods" automatically to the store.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you want the selector instead of an action. Redux toolkit exports the ```createSelector``` from the reselect library. https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSelector

Comment: These are just normal selectors and do not even need the `createSelector` utility.
You might consider to not export the full slice, but parts of it:
`export const {reducer, actions} = mySlice`
and then just export your selectors alongside that.